# Could not fetch /content/drive/MyDrive/Bitlabs/ICT8/PrivateKey from backend

Tags: python, pandas, backend, private-key

So i am trying to import PrivateKey from Gdrive to Collab but it's said "Could not fetch /content/drive/MyDrive/Bitlabs/ICT8/PrivateKey from backend"

[This is my drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8512.png)

[And This is the problem i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLsDu.png)

is that something wrong with my "/content/drive/MyDrive/Bitlabs/ICT8/PrivateKey" ? i don't using whitespace too because it's can't too

Answer (score -1):

Problem Solved, i just copy path from gdrive and it's work /content/drive/MyDrive/Bitlabs/ICT 8/PrivateKey/private-key.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXIeq.png)